# jquery file uploader was working fine with grails version 2.4.5 but when we switched to grails 5.1.2 then uploader does not picks file less than 100kb

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jquery-file-upload

Uploader is reading any file  larger than 100kb but files having size lower than 100kb multipartFile object is null

The command object is

```
class UploadInfoListCommand implements Validateable{   MultipartFile infoMasterFile   String localeFileileExtension

  static constraints = {
    infoMasterFile  validator: { val, obj ->
      if ( val == null ) {
        return false
      }
      if ( val.empty ) {
        return false
      }

      ['xlsx'].any { extension -> // <1>
        val.originalFilename?.toLowerCase()?.endsWith(extension)
      }
    }   }
```

and the GSP code is

```
<div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="${message(code:'info.uploadModal.language.placeholder.file', default:'Please select a document')}" id="bulkUploadDocumentInfo"/>
                <label class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" for="bulkUploadDocument">
                  <input type="file" id="bulkUploadDocument" name="infoMasterFile" style="display:none;" data-validate="maxFileSizeMB(5)" onchange="$('#bulkUploadDocumentInfo').val(this.files[0].name);">
                  <g:message code="info.uploadModal.language.label.searchFile" default="Add New File" />
               </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `val.originalFilename`, `val.empty` evaluate to when the file is there but less than 100kb?

Comment: When the file is less than 100kn then the MultipartFile object is null, when its greater than 100kb then it has some value.

Comment: "When the file is less than 100kn then the MultipartFile object is null, when its greater than 100kb then it has some value." - That is interesting.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues with a sample app we can investigate.  I am sorry for the trouble and thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Did you find the reason/a solution?